# Empty GroupID sonar eclipse

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I'm using Maven And Sonar with eclipse. I already have my maven projects on LocalHost 9000.
But when i go to eclipse configure>associate with sonar says that my groupId is empty. I think thats not supposed to happen. Anybody know how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same issue, the tricks here are:

1. The key of the sonar project must follow the naming convention, [groupid]:[artifactid]. They are separated by a ":".  For example, if the key *com.example:sample*, then the groupid is *com.example*, artifactid is *sample*.
2. The eclipse project name must be same as the artifactid (**case-sensitive**).

So, you need to 1) change the sonar project key to the naming convention above, 2) change the eclipse project name to the artifactid.  Then eclipse will be able to automatically link your eclipse project to sonar project when your click the button "Find on server".

Answer (score 3):

Few things to check:-

1. Check the `groupId` is actually there in your `pom.xml`.
2. Check that the `artifactId` and the eclipse project name are the same.
3. Check that you typed `groupId` and `artifactId` in the `associate with sonar` dialog window. Then click `find on server`.
4. Also make sure that the sonar plugin is set up on your eclipse (by going to `Windows->Preferences->Sonar`).

HTH.

Comment: Have the same issue but with the sonar ANT task, there doesn't seem be to be a way to define the groupId and artifactid via the properties.

Comment: There is no properties named groupid or artifactid in the ant script.  You need to set the key of the project to groupid:artifactid. see my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

It got fixed by following the instructions mentioned [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Ant+Task)

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem in my setup with Jenkins running Ant and sending the data to Sonar. I had to add in
projectKey=com.mycompany:projectNameInEclipse 
either to the sonar properties or into the Project properties for Sonar in Jenkins. (I had projectKey=projectname which won't work)

Update: by doing this way, it created a new project in Sonar with the same name but with the new key. The proper way to do it is to change the sonar property as above then configure the project in Sonar (Configuration->Update Key) and set that to the proper key. Now when you run the analysis the new run will go into the old Sonar project (with the new key).